# How does MongoDB keep a numeric column, which is indexed, always sorted if the column is constantly updated?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, indexing, nosql

What happens after an update to this column is made? What does MongoDB do? What is the time-complexity to keep this column sorted after each update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't keep the documents sorted.

The index entries are stored in a btree-like structure.  When a value is updated, the entry containing the old entry is removed, and a new entry is inserted at the appropriate point in the tree.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Insertion) reports the time complexity of both insert and delete in a btree as O(log n).